# How to define named scope/class query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, methods, named, scopes

I'm having difficulty understanding how to define a scope/class method in my Rails application.

Basically, here is the query that I want it to do:

```
self.visible(current_user) -> {
@requests.where.not(visible==group && (request.user.group != 
current_user.group))}
```

Basically, it's a site where users can make posts/requests, but I wanted the poster to be able to limit the visibility of the post (ie, so that if they selected the option where visible = "group", then other users outside of that group cannot see it (only users that share the same 'group' can see that post).

Please help me with the syntax, I couldn't figure out how to use the AND condition in the WHERE statement.

Right now, I have:

```
scope :visible, -> (group) { joins(:user).where.not(visible: 'group', 
users:{group: group}).references(:users)}
```

which returns the opposite of what I want.
However, when I remove the not, it doesn't give me anything.

thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship between your models?  In the scope written thus far you reference a group and user object, but I'm not sure precisely where the scope is being defined, and how it relates to the other models.

Comment: Actually, in the user table, there is user.group (where group references the name of the group as a string). It's simple right now, where I have the user give the group as a string- there isn't a separate column for groups).
In the request table, i have request.visible, which the user/poster will select as the 'visibility group'. ie, as a poster, I might be part of a group called 'rock band' and I input 'rock band' as the group (user.group = 'rock band') , and my request.visible = group, so the controller needs to recognize that request.visible = group and allow rock band members to see it.

Comment: Sorry, the scope is in the requests model. I want to be able to exclude requests where the poster indicates that only a member of the same group (named via string) can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this.

```
scope :visible, -> (group) { joins(:user).where("visible <> 'group' OR (visible = 'group' AND users.group = ?)", group) }
```

Comment: Hey I tried it, and it sort of worked. The visibility did have its intended effect, but it also filtered out other posts that should be seen as well. For example, if posts don't have a visible (request.visible = 'nil'), then it should be displayed, regardless of whether the users share the same group or not.

Sorry, but what is the '<>' shortcut for/mean ? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. This WORKS! 
It seemed like it didn't work because I had previous posts that didn't have a visibility attribute. 
What is the '<>' operator? Thank so much!

Comment: In SQL, `<>` is the _not equal_ operator, equivalent to `!=` in most other languages.